# PLS-00221: 'insert_order' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: java, oracle

I want to call function with java jpa hibernate

I try with this code :

```
  String input=   "{ \"p_principal\":\r\n" + 
          "                                [\r\n" + 
          "                                    {\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_emp\": 200,\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_request\": 23,\r\n" + 
          "                                 \"p_date\": \"23-10-2024\",\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_info\": \"test\"\r\n" + 
          "                                    }\r\n" + 
          "                                ]\r\n" + 
          "                                ,\"p_detail\":\r\n" + 
          "                                [\r\n" + 
          "                                    {\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_emp\": 200,\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_date\": \"23-10-2024\",\r\n" + 
          "                                    \"p_info\": \"test\"\r\n" + 
          "                                    }\r\n" + 
          "                                ]\r\n" + 
          "                        }";

     Query query = em
            .createNativeQuery("{call integ_pkg.insert_order(:input)} ");
    query.setParameter("input", input);
    
    BigInteger result = (BigInteger) query.getResultList().get(0);
    System.out.println("result    :"+result);
```

but when I test the code I have this error :

```
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'insert_order' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

as an information **insert_order** in oracle database is a function

this is the test directly in database :

```
declare
    request_detail clob := '{ "p_principal":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "p_emp": 200,
                                    "p_request": 23,
                                    "p_date": "23-10-2024",
                                    "p_info": "test"
                                    }
                                ]
                                ,"p_detail":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "p_emp": 200,
                                    "p_date": "23-10-2024",
                                    "p_info": "test"
                                    }
                                ]
                        }';
    json_out                    clob;
begin

json_out := integ_pkg.insert_order(request_detail);
dbms_output.put_line(json_out);
end;
```

the output is like this :

```
    {"p_principal":[{"p_num_generate":15,"p_error":null}]
,"p_detail":[{"p_emp":200,"p_error":null}]}
```

the problem is to know how call the function using java jpa hibernate

**updated :**

I try with this code :

```
Query query = em
            .createNativeQuery("select integ_pkg.insert_order(:input)} from dual");
    query.setParameter("input", input);
    
    String  result = (String) query.getResultList().get(0);
    System.out.println("result    :"+result);
```

but I have this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> PLS-00221: 'insert_order' is not a procedure or is undefined

You said

> insert_order in oracle database is a function

and your test calls it as a function. So the error is correct - it is not a procedure, it is a function, and you are calling it as a procedure in `"{call integ_pkg.insert_order(:input)}"`, as you are not allowing for the return value.

You can call it with assignment of the return value to another placeholder, with something like

```
"{:output = integ_pkg.insert_order(:input)}"
```

or

```
"{:output = call integ_pkg.insert_order(:input)}"
```

but then you have to get the result out, which I don't think JPA supports in this form (at least in JPA 2.0 - don't know much about it but looking at  [their wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures)).

Instead, you can call the function as part of a query:

```
"{select integ_pkg.insert_order(:input) from dual}"
```

which will return the CLOB result - though as a String, not a BigInteger; your current result retrieval looks odd...

Comment: thank you for your response,
 
 I have updated my question , I follow your code but I have error

Comment: @franco - you've got a stray `}` in your version. Ah, I did originally have that in my answer but fixed that 4 hours ago *8-) And I put `"{select integ_pkg.insert_order(:input) from dual}"` but it's probably just `"select integ_pkg.insert_order(:input) from dual"` without any curly braces; but either way not just the single closing one.

Comment: thank you for your response, I try with :

select integ_pkg.insert_order(:input) from dual

 but now I have this error :
  ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
  
      because insert_order modifies 
data with update statement so I think that I should call function with other way

Comment: @franco - yes; though I'd prefer to use a procedure with an OUT parameter for the result if it's changing data, rather than a function. Either way, based on the wiki I linked to, it looks like you need JPA 2.1 and a different approach. You may need to ask a new question if you can't make that work.

Comment: thank you, I will try to find a solution using a procedure with an OUT parameter for the result